# The data types varchar and varbinary are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need to query sys.database_principals based on sid, but I am getting below exception

```
The data types varchar and varbinary are incompatible in the add operator.
```

```
DECLARE @applicationusername VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE @applicationsid varbinary(85)
Declare @q  varchar(max)
SET @applicationusername = 'test123'
SET @applicationsid = 0x........    -- some valid varbinary

set @q = 'SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name =''' + @applicationusername +''' AND [sid] = '+@applicationsid +' '
Print @q

EXEC (@q)
```

Comment: You probably need to CAST or CONVERT your varbinary to a varchar first.

Answer (score 2):

No need for dynamic SQL here.  Just plug the variables into the static SQL.

```
DECLARE @applicationusername VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE @applicationsid varbinary(85)
Declare @q nvarchar(max)
SET @applicationusername = 'test123'
SET @applicationsid = 0xa2827e2f0    -- some valid varbinary


SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals 
WHERE name = @applicationusername 
AND [sid] = @applicationsid
```

And even with dynamic SQL, still use parameters, instead of pasting the variables into the SQL string.

```
DECLARE @applicationusername VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE @applicationsid varbinary(85)
Declare @q nvarchar(max)
SET @applicationusername = 'test123'
SET @applicationsid = 0xa2827e2f0    -- some valid varbinary

set @q = N'
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals 
  WHERE name = @applicationusername 
    AND [sid] = @applicationsid'

Print @q

exec sp_executesql @q, 
     N'@applicationusername varchar(50), @applicationsid varbinary(85)', 
     @applicationusername =@applicationusername , 
     @applicationsid = @applicationsid
```

and if you ever did need to convert a varbinary value into a TSQL literal, you can do it with convert,  eg

```
select convert(varchar(200), @applicationsid, 1)
```

outputs

```
0x0A2827E2F0
```